# Get person name first and retrieve external data with COUNT based on this name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making a sports solution to retrieve data from play by play to webpage.
And now I am stuck with a moment to retrieve player name from mysql db, put to boxscore table (that was done), and then retrieve all stats based on this name.
As example - how many points he made, how many assists were associated with his name, etc.

At the end I want to get this kind of table (all formating /styling done and ready):

[image]

Here is a php code, question based in the "echo" point.
I cant finnd proper way to count how many assists a.e. player made in the same request.

```
<?php

require "connection.php";

$game_id = 1760;
$player = 'KURBANOV, NIKITA';
$team = 'CSKA Moscow';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM game_results WHERE game_id = :game_id AND team = :team AND action = "Assist" ORDER BY player DESC');
$stmt->execute(array('game_id' => $game_id, 'team' => $team ));
$result = $stmt -> fetchAll();

echo '<table class="table table-condensed table-hover"><tbody>';
echo '<thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>POS</th>
                  <th>MIN</th>
                  <th>PTS</th>
                  <th>OREB</th>
                  <th>DREB</th>
                  <th>TREB</th>
                  <th>AST</th>
                  <th>STL</th>
                  <th>TOV</th>
                  <th>Fm</th>
                  <th>Fc</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>';

foreach( $result as $row ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['player'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['action'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_id'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Here is the db data example:

[DB example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abCFk.gif)

Comment: Could you please specify what you are trying to archive and what you have tried?

Comment: @Feirell edited the post. You can see in the beggining of it that I am trying to load Name of the person, and based on it - load data from mysql database (game results) how many times he made a shot, he missed, he got rebound. In the database there is an action column with this info (Off Rebound, Def Rebound). Row in this table also has name of the person. So now I need to load Name of the person, and based on it COUNT how much rebounds, points he got. Tried "COUNT(*)", and PDO version. But it is hard for me to understand how to retrieve all data by one SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

Ok after your edit I think I guessed what you want to do.

You want to count how many entrys you have in your table of a specific player and a specific action.

```
SELECT player,
    Count(CASE action
            WHEN 'Assist' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            end) AS assists,
    Count(CASE action
            WHEN '<other case>' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            end) AS other_case
FROM   `game_results`
WHERE  1
GROUP  BY player
```

This above SQL Select should do what you want, replace `other case` with what ever you else have.

EDIT:

You should be able to print it out just like you did before:

```
<?php
// your other code ...
echo '<table class="table table-condensed table-hover"><tbody>';
echo '<thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>assists</th>
                <th>other case</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>';

foreach( $result as $row ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['player'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['assits'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['other_case'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it now.
Can you help me with one thing more.How can I request player name and make it primary request, and then load Case constructions mentioned in your answer and put this data to same row in the html table. By "foreach" I assume?

Comment: @dow_jones what do you mean by "How can I request player name and make it primary request"? If you want to list only one specific player you can add your `WHERE` clause from your question where I have the placeholder `1`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, and understood the logic how to retrieve data of one player. But now error hits me

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Count(CASE action WHEN 'Assist' THEN 1 ELSE 0 ' at line 2 in

Comment: Code I have now

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT player, game_id
    Count(CASE action
            WHEN \'Assist\' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            end) AS assists,
    Count(CASE action
            WHEN \'<other case>\' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            end) AS other_case
FROM   game_results
WHERE  team = :team AND game_id = :game_id
GROUP  BY player');
$stmt->execute(array('game_id' => $game_id, 'team' => $team ));
$result = $stmt -> fetchAll();

Comment: That should work. Try the statement in some development console (like phpMyAdmin) to see if everything works as expectet.